# How to map a list of Java exceptions to customer visible error codes

Tags: java, exception

I'm designing a Java exception handling mechanism for a 2 component system {front-end, back-end}. The back-end will generate exceptions by using Exception classes for different error conditions. Front-end has to map those exception classes to a customer visible error code. This list of Exception classes can be pretty big and may continue to increase in size. What is the best way to map those Exception classes to customer visible error codes?

I could create a `Map<Class, Integer> MAP_EX_CLASS_TO_ERROR_CODE` and keep it updated, but is it the right/scalable way to map exceptions?

------- Edits after receiving initial set of answers, see Comments below ----

I want to represent similar types of exceptions, or exceptions that demand similar handling with one exception class. For e.g. `UserExceptions` can be:

- RESOURCE_NAME_TOO_LONG
- RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND
- RESOURCE_NOT_OWNED
  ...

and `InternalExceptions` can be:

- SERVER_UNAVAILABLE
- REQUEST_TIMEOUT
  ...

If I make an enum for all these error codes, then is it still useful to implement the grouping? I wanted to do the grouping instead of defining one single class for checked exceptions because it'll force me to pay attention to the catch-ing of exceptions every time I add a new line of code that throws a different checked exception than existing code.

for e.g.

```
public enum ECodes {
     RESOURCE_NAME_TOO_LONG(/*number*/0, UserException.class),
     RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND(1, UserException.class),
     RESOURCE_NOT_OWNED(2, UserException.class),
     SERVER_UNAVAILABLE(3, InternalException.class),
     REQUEST_TIMEOUT(4, InternalException.class);

     // constructor and stuff
}

public class Prot1ExceptionMapper {
     static Map<Ecode, /*CustomerCode*/Integer> MAP_EX_CLASS_TO_ERROR_CODE = new HashMap<>(); 

     static {
         MAP_EX_CLASS_TO_ERROR_CODE.add(Ecode.RESOURCE_NAME_TOO_LONG, PROT1_CUSTOMER_CODE1);
         // Other mappings here
     }

     public static Integer map(Ecode ecode) {
         // Lookup ecode
     }
}

public class Prot2ExceptionMapper {
     static Map<Ecode, /*CustomerCode*/Integer> MAP_EX_CLASS_TO_ERROR_CODE = new HashMap<>(); 

     static {
         MAP_EX_CLASS_TO_ERROR_CODE.add(Ecode.RESOURCE_NAME_TOO_LONG, PROT2_CUSTOMER_CODE1);
         // Other mappings here
     }

     public static Integer map(Ecode ecode) {
         // Lookup ecode
     }
}

public class UserException extends Exception {
     public UserException(ECodes ecode, String message) {
         assert ecode.class == UserException.class;
     }
}

public class InternalException extends Exception {
     public InternalException(ECodes ecode, String message) {
       assert ecode.class == UserException.class;
     }
}

class DummyClass {
  public void doFirstJob() throws UserException {}
  public void doSecondJob() throws InternalException {}
}

class Protocol1MainClass {
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
      try {
         doFirstJob();
         doSecondJob();
      } catch (UserException e1) {
         // Do UserException specific stuff
         throw Prot1ExceptionMapper.map(e1);
      } catch (InternalException e2) {
         // Do InternalException specific stuff
         throw Prot1ExceptionMapper.map(e2);
      }
```

Comment: Exceptions should indicate exceptional circumstances. If you're dealing with expected error codes, I would go with an enum instead. It's easier to maintain and less expensive performance-wise.

Comment: I am indeed dealing with circumstances that are clearly defined in the protocol spec. The back-end server I'm writing is protocol agnostic and returns internal error codes to indicate failures such as RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND, the front-end has to determine the protocol  failed request was using and translate that internal exception to customer visible error code.

Comment: Then why use exceptions altogether? Just create a predefined set of errors in a readily consumable format - like an enum.

Comment: Exceptions should be handled where they occur. One way to handle them is to log the actual exception, create a user-visible message, restore the program to a valid state, display the message, then proceed. Exceptions shouldn't be naïvely mapped to user-visible messages but rather carefully transformed into a crafted, useful interaction. User experience über alles. Don't neglect logging the actual exceptions.

Comment: Please see my edits, I've added sample code to the question. +1 for logging the exception